# React Native: borderRadius on nested image not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used a nested image, so I can have a placeholder while an image is loading, the border radius on the outer image is not working at all

```
      <Image
        style={{
          width: imageWidth / 1.5,
          height: imageWidth / 1.5,
          borderRadius: imageWidth,
        }}
        source={placeholder}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            width: imageWidth / 1.5,
            height: imageWidth / 1.5,
            borderRadius: imageWidth,
          }}
          source={{uri: 'some https image source'}
        />
      </Image>
```

it will look like this:

[image]

any ideas on how I can fix this or implement a placeholder some other way.

Comment: Try setting a `backgroundColor` instead of using nested `Image` components.

Comment: Also, try setting the `borderRadius` as a prop to the `Image` component, like `<Image borderRadius={imageWidth} ... />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im using the following at the moment, on iOS you have to have a View wrapping an image for the image to display.

```
<TouchableOpacity
          style={[CommonStyles.PlaceholderColor,
            { width: imageWidth / 1.75,
              height: imageWidth / 1.75,
              borderRadius: imageWidth }]}
          onPress={() => {
            InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
              Actions.friendProfile({ user });
            });
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              width: imageWidth / 1.75,
              height: imageWidth / 1.75,
              borderRadius: imageWidth,
              overflow: 'hidden'
            }}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: imageWidth / 1.75,
                height: imageWidth / 1.75,
                ...Platform.select({
                  android: {
                    borderRadius: imageWidth
                  }
                })
              }}
              source={source}
            />
          </View>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, though it may not be the most efficient, I think that you can accomplish this via using a method.

So something like....

```
// ....other code
showImage(){
    if (not ready){
        return 'a different URI';
    }
    return 'original URI'
}

render(){
    renturn (
        <Image
            style={{
                width: imageWidth / 1.5,
                height: imageWidth / 1.5,
                borderRadius: imageWidth,
            }}
            source={this.showImage.bind(this)}
        />
)}
```

You can also apply this same logic while using state, though considering I don't know the extent of your program, changing state may not be ideal.

Comment: How are you doing this part right now?

"I used a nested image, so I can have a placeholder while an image is loading, the border radius on the outer image is not working at all"

Answer (score 0):

For people having issues with borderRadius of image etc - after hunting around this was only thing that worked for me:
[About React Example](https://aboutreact.com/example-to-set-border-radius-of-an-image-in-react-native/)
Basically - you need to use the enclosing view to set size and borders, and also have basic dimensions in the image itself